# Calculate duration of task

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Say I have some task to process 100 days of data, and it takes 5 hrs to process a day. But each day that it takes to process it a new day of data comes in.

So for the initial set of data it takes:
5 hrs/day * 100 days to process = 500 hours ~= 21 days

In that time you get ~21 more days of data:
5 hrs/day * 500/24 days to process ~= 104 hrs

And so forth..

How can I calculate when this will catch up?

Comment: You tagged this as sequences and series. Do you want us to use an infinite geometric series to solve this problem?

Comment: Trying to create an ETA for a customer, which is possible with brute force, but then I became more interested how to solve this problem generically.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I would like to solve the problem in whatever way is most direct. If I should tag something else I'd be more than happy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that it takes $r$ fraction of a day to process one day’s worth of data, where $r<1$, and we start with $d_0$ days’ worth of data. It takes $rd_0$ days to process the initial backlog, then $r(rd_0)=r^2d_0$ days to process what arrives during the processing of the initial backlog, and so on. Thus, the total processing time required in order to catch up is

$$rd_0+r^2d_0+r^3d_0+\ldots=rd_0\sum_{k\ge 0}r^k=\frac{rd_0}{1-r}$$

days. In your case $r=\frac5{24}$, $d_0=100$, and you get

$$\frac{500/24}{19/24}=\frac{500}{19}\approx 26\text{ days, }7\text{ hours, }35\text{ minutes.}$$